# Schedule on Mobile. To drill down or not to drill down?

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, drilldown

One aspect of the app I am working on is an employee schedule. The main functionalities are to include an employee's schedule for the current day and the next 7 upcoming days.

The information to be seen is:

- The job time
- Job name
- Job description (usually three words long)
- The manager they will be working for with a link to their phone number
- The explicit address listed and a link to a google map of it
- The ability to accept the job once they've read the information of it. The accept button should also be prominent and should have a second confirmation accept somehow.

With all these tasks in mind for one schedule, is it beneficial to drill in? Or could this be cleanly laid out in one screen? Perhaps with drop-downs?

Comment: Who don't you try both and see which one is more usable by conducting a user testing? The best is to validate your design with the users. :)

Comment: @Gawnu thanks for your contribution to the UXSE pool of knowledge! Your answer has been converted to a comment but please feel free to do some research or come up with a design concept if you would like to submit an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. It's possible

I think you should categorize information in ranges of similar usability or common part.

You should consider navigation over time and extract information that is independent over time

Another possibility that I see is to create a submenu with tabs containing categorized information at the top

Have a nice day :)